# SignalR - WebSockets to ServerSentEvents - Issue

Tags: websocket, signalr, server-sent-events

I'm using SignalR v2.0 on Windows Server 2012 with IIS8,
I enabled WebSockets on the server by the following article,
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support

But signalR first tries to work with websockets, and right after that change the transport to serverSentEvents

The negotiation response is `TryWebSockets=True`

The response header of connecting with websockets is

- Upgrade: Websocket
- X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
- Connection: Upgrade
- with status code 101 (Switching Protocols)

All my solution's projects are using .NET4.5

I also saw the following message in the Event Viewer (not sure if it is relevant)

> Exception information: 
>       Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
>       Exception message: Unrecognized user identity.  The user identity cannot change during an active SignalR connection.    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.GetConnectionId(HostContext
>   context, String connectionToken)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(HostContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ProcessRequest(HostContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(IDictionary`2
>   environment)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.Middleware.HubDispatcherMiddleware.Invoke(IOwinContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the user's identity during an active connection. It means you're probably doing something like logging in a user without stopping the connection first.

Comment: Hi David, first - thank you for you response, you mean that before posting the authentication form, I need to call "$.connection.hub.stop();" ?

Comment: also, do you have any idea why signalR change the transport from websockets to serversentevents ? is it related ?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe you have a server side exception causing it to fallback. If you turn logging on ($.connection.hub.logging = true) it'll show you what SignalR is doing

Comment: i will look for that, and be back soon with an answer, thank you :)

Comment: Hi, i see on the log that it is a timeout issue when trying to connect to "ws://...", i'm working on IIS8 with Windows Server 2012, is there any special settings I need to change ? could it be related to firewall ?

Comment: Could be anything but this isn't the place to ask these kinds of questions. Either create a new question of use the signalr forum or jabbr room.